# How to ssh port forward into a server to access a mysql host server for local work on Django web app and Jupyter notebook?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, ssh-keys, openssh, ssh-tunnel

I'm unfamiliar with this terrain, so if any one can guide me in a step by step manner- it would really help. My MySQL database sits on a AWS host X- "ec2-xxx-xxx-xxx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com". It is blocked to access from individual local machines and is usually accessed from another working server Y- "ec2-yy-yyy-yyy-yy.compute-1.amazonaws.com" through port '3306'. Now it is especially inconvenient to access this via terminal SSH every time and scripts while they run, its hard to prototype or build an elaborate app. I'd like to set up a SSH tunnel from my local to server Y to be able to access MySQL host X from my local machine, to run queries from my locally deployed Jupyter notebook as well as local working-in-progress Django web app.

The reason why I ask for something more step-by-step is that I have to port forward to another server hosting a redis database which again is accessible through a specific server only. So, I'll be able to carry the solution from here to there too. I'm willing to go into chat as well if needed, but I need to resolve this rather quickly. Thanks!

PS: I've tried many guides off of the internet, but nothing has worked, it's become clear to me that I'm missing some foundational understanding or pathway. That's why I'm here, trying to start from the ground.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SSH tunnel: local => gateway => MySQL server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12494695/ssh-tunnel-local-gateway-mysql-server)

Comment: I think I did this, how do I check if its worked? And do I need some special command or set -up to use the port for running queries from my local Jupyter notebook? Because I did this for my redis server (similar gateway paradigm) and my notebook isn;t able to connect still- not sure what I'm missing.